# Access to values of a double pointer of integers in a function in C

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, sudoku

In a SUDOKU project, I created a function to type in a dynamic matrix and fill it, however I can't figure out how to use the values of this dynamic matrix in other functions, to be precise I don't know how to pass the matrix as a function parameter in order to change or make some tests on its values.

For example, the function typematrix has this header:

```
int **typematrix();
```

If for example I wanted to show the values of this matrix using a created function, named for example showMatrixValues, I wrote like so:

```
void showMatrixValues(int **matrix[9][9]);
```

Yet somehow I get errors on conflicting types or the fact that I'm passing an argument makes pointer without cast when using both functions in main, using a local variable:

```
   int  **matrix[9][9];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). You need to show your code. Note that `int **ptrptrint` and `int matrix[9][9]` are very different types with completely different storage requirements, even if you use `ptrptrint[8][8]` and `matrix[8][8]` to access the bottom-right corner of the data. The access path is also quite different; one involves two memory reads, the other just one; one involves multiplication, the other doesn't. And `int **matrix[9][9]` is different again — and wrong.

Comment: "Yet somehow I get errors" What did you expect to get? `int **[9][9]` is different from `int **`.

Comment: Out of interest, could you not code this in C++?

Comment: Since `typematrix` returns an `int **` value, that is what you should pass to `showMatrixValues`: `void showMatrixValues(int **matrix);`.